# function doesn't want to fire

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't understand why the `check()` function doesn't want to fire, I know that if I set this function to `setInterval(check, 1000)` or to function `$("#btn-click")` it will work but why it doesn't work now? I would appreciate if you explain me

```js
$(function() {
  $("#field").on("keyup", function() {
    var x = $(this).val();
    $("#outcome").text(x);
  });

  $("#btn-save").click(function() {
    var name = $("#outcome").text();
    var x = $("table tbody").append("<tr><td>" + name + "</td></tr>")
    $("#field").val("");
    $("#outcome").text("");
  });

  check();

  function check() {
    if ($("table tbody").has("tr")) {
      $("table tbody tr td").on("click", function(e) {
        var tar = $(e.target);
        var b = $(this);
        if (tar.is(b)) {
          b.css("color", "red");
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <input type='text' id='field'>
  <p>The result is: <span id="outcome"></span></p>
  <span id="btn-save" class="btn-save">save</span>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Names</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: `check()` is firing absolutely fine - your issue is that there are no `table tbody tr td` elements, so you're not adding any click event handlers. Also your `e.target`/`tar.is()` check is redundant. They will always match

Comment: *function doesn't want to fire* Then let it R.I.P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function fires, but there's no td element to attach events to.

If you want to bind events to elements that will be dynamically generated, you do not need a check function, just use `$(body').on(evtType,selector,handler)`

Check below for an example. every td you'll add dynamically will still be bound to the event listener, because it's attached to 'body'.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#field").on("keyup", function() {
    var x = $(this).val();
    $("#outcome").text(x);
  });

  $("#btn-save").click(function() {
    var name = $("#outcome").text();
    var x = $("table tbody").append("<tr><td>" + name + "</td></tr>")
    $("#field").val("");
    $("#outcome").text("");
  });

  check();

  function check() {
      console.log('firing')
  }

  $('body').on('click', 'table tbody tr td', function(e) {
    var tar = $(e.target);
    var b = $(this);
    if (tar.is(b)) {
      b.css("color", "red");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <input type='text' id='field'>
  <p>The result is: <span id="outcome"></span>
  </p>
  <span id="btn-save" class="btn-save">save</span>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Names</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`check()` is firing. It's just not doing anything because of your `if` logic, which had bad selectors pointing to elements (`tbody`, `td`) that you don't have.

You won't get a `td` element in your table until AFTER you click `btn-save` because that `click` event handler creates the `td` elements. Your code wants to run `check` before that button gets clicked.

I've removed the reference to `tbody` and changed your `td` reference to `th` and now it works:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#field").on("keyup", function() {
        var x = $(this).val();
        $("#outcome").text(x);
    });

    $("#btn-save").click(function() {
        var name = $("#outcome").text();
        var x = $("table tbody").append("<tr><td>" +name+"</td></tr>")
        $("#field").val("");
        $("#outcome").text("");
    });

    check();
    function check() {
      console.log("HELLO FROM CHECK!");
        if ($("table").has("tr")) {
            $("table tr th").on("click", function(e) {
                var tar = $(e.target);
                var b = $(this);
                if (tar.is(b)) {
                    b.css("color", "red");
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='field'>
        <p>The result is: <span id="outcome"></span></p>
        <span id="btn-save" class="btn-save">save</span>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Names</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```